# If-else statement for changing levels

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I have a got a function for changing levels in my game. In the game, the first level changes to the second level correctly. But the second level changes to the first level too, then count = 4. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
public void CheckLevelCompletion() {
    if ((count == 4) && (levelOneCompleted == false)) {
        img.sprite = levelCompletedImage;
        count = 0;
        levelOneCompleted = true;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("FifthGameSecondLevel");
    }
    else if ((count == 6) && (levelOneCompleted == true))
    {
        img.sprite = levelCompletedImage;
        count = 0;
        levelTwoCompleted = true;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("FifthGameThirdLevel");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: You need to post more code parts, like where is `count` populated, what is the variable scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your code steps, but maybe it is this situation, I think. 
If scene reloaded, your game object in previous scene is destroyed.
So `levelOneCompleted` is always `false`.
It is why `SceneManager.LoadScene("FifthGameThirdLevel");` does not run.

If it is right, I recommend `levelOneCompleted` make public and set `true` in second level game object.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that the variable levelOneCompleted does not change its value, but I don't know why. In the start of program it's value is false. But in the branch if ((count == 4) && (levelOneCompleted == false))   value should be changed to true, but nothing happens. What should I do?

Comment: Or you could make it a `static` variable so that it can maintain its value

Comment: Don't make things static for that reason, that's awful and not what static is for. `static` is for properties that aren't linked to a specific instance of a class, `Math.Pi` for example: it doesn't make sense to ever call `new Math()` so all of its fields and methods are static.